# how can I call latitude and longitude in weather activity from google map activity?

Tags: android, google-maps

i ve already started the weather activity using OnMapClickListener method. this weather activity shows data from lat long info in weather api. what i want to achive is to call that coordinates from Google map. after user long click the map, weather sctivity starts  and Show the data depending on the coordinates when user clicks on map.

thanks in advance for any ideas .

Comment: Where is weather activity code? Where is google maps code that you tried and is not working?

Comment: @Talha no i havent tried anything . but with OnMapLongClick method i started the weather activity. i dont know how to call and use the coordinates .

Comment: Please post some code so it can be better understood.